# Komodo Edit does not support shtml code hinting?

Tags: ide, komodo, komodoedit, shtml

I have searched a lot about this feature but it seems that Komodo edit does not support any shtml intellisense.

I cannot believe this as I finally found a great HTML/CSS/JavaScript/jQuery editor but no SHTML support! I thought that I have finally found a replacement for Dreamweaver but without SHTML code hinting, it is a deal breaker for me. The problem is that I work a lot with the technologies mentioned but I also work a lot with SHTML. I googled a lot but I haven't even found a post about this matter! I cannot believe how this is possible.

Do you know how to enable SHTML intellisense for Komode Edit? Is it even possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for this.

I added the .shtml file type in Edit, Preferences, File Associations. I Linked the .shtml file type to be read as usual HTML.

However, in Komodo Edit, I found out that when you are coding HTML, the classes for instance do not load automatically. You have to manually click CTRL + Space and this only gets you the class which the application thinks you need to use. A list with all the classes beginning with a particular character does not show up.

Comment: but, at least on my case, it shows up as you type. Maybe because your extension is SHTML